# Customize Look and feel Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How can I customize the images of the components in the Nimbus Look and Feel? I would like to create the images in photoshop and place
on some Nimbus Look and Feel components, these are the components that I want to change:

ScrollBar Button
Knob ScrollBar
Thumb ScrollBar
ScrollBar Track

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best resource for nimbus is the Oracle website itself [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/color.html). However it mostly outlines customizing the theme via the api and allows customisation of components outwith your program via xml in a somewhat restricted way, to quote another post here

For accessing and modifying the elements you reference this is a useful resource [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) you can then call the ui manager to apply any modifications you wish in a way such as this:

`UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("control", new Color(..`

Again there is a useful link [here](https://lifeflowproject.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/customizing-java-look-and-feel/) that goes into more detail.about applying colours etc to your ui.

There is also lengthy posts  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197505/set-the-button-background-of-a-nimbus-button) about using images to modify the themes, but Imo your best bet would be to follow this guide [which outlines the xml format for plaf.synth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) which allows loading of xml purely for customizable themes so pretty much ideal for someone who is using photoshop:

```
<style id="buttonStyle">
   <insets top="15" left="20" right="20" bottom="15"/>
   <state>
      <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button.png"
        sourceInsets="10 10 10 10"/>
   </state>
</style>
<bind style="buttonStyle" type="region" key="button"/>
```

and get the resource with your theme:

```
 private static String synthFile = "buttonSkin.xml";
 private static void initLookAndFeel() {
       // String lookAndFeel = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel";
       SynthLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = new SynthLookAndFeel();


            try {
                lookAndFeel.load(SynthApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(synthFile),
                                  SynthApplication.class);
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
            } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't get specified look and feel ("
                                   + lookAndFeel
                                   + "), for some reason.");
                System.err.println("Using the default look and feel.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

A full sample is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/lookandfeel/SynthApplicationProject/src/lookandfeel/SynthApplication.java)